# Is it possible to detokenize DataFrame in PySpark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, nlp, tokenize

I'm using app.zelp.com to perform NLP. After tokenization and removing the stopwords, I would like to detokenize the remaining words and export to csv. Is that possible?

```
%python
# Start Spark session
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("StopWords").getOrCreate()
from pyspark.ml.feature import Tokenizer, StopWordsRemover 
from pyspark import SparkFiles
url ="myamazon s3 url"
spark.sparkContext.addFile(url)
df = spark.read.csv(SparkFiles.get("myfile.csv"), sep=",", header=True)

# Tokenize DataFrame
review_data = Tokenizer(inputCol="Text", outputCol="Words")
# Transform DataFrame
reviewed = review_data.transform(df)
# Remove stop words
remover = StopWordsRemover(inputCol="Words", outputCol="filtered")
newFrame = remover.transform(reviewed)

final = newFrame.select("filtered")
```

I would like to combine the remaining words and export to csv. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

you can consider tokenizing with Spark-NLP Tokenizer, and then assembling back the tokens using the TokenAssembler,

https://nlp.johnsnowlabs.com/docs/en/transformers#tokenassembler-getting-data-reshaped

Alberto.